# Live reload preview just reloads forever

Tags: admin, post-editor, previews

There is a new preview feature on WordPress that looks like this:

[image: live reload preview menu]

When it's clicked, it reloads the preview over and over and over again.

Why would this happen? I tried disabling different plugins and nothing works.

I checked my console and tried to grab the errors but I can't because the page reloads over and over again.

Is this a known bug? Why is this happening? How do I even start to debug this?

Comment: it says it will automatically reload the preview to show changes in the editor, is that not what you're seeing? The browser console can be set to preserve the log in its settings, otherwise it sounds like it's doing what it says it was going to do. By the way, how are you seeing this user interface and where is it located in the editor? My preview menu does not show that option despite running the latest Gutenberg

Comment: I can find no references to any of the text in your screenshot when searching the WP core and Gutenberg git repos on github, please provide more information about this live preview in new tab feature shown in your screenshot, where it's located in the UI etc. As far as I can see, this is not a WordPress feature, it's been added by 3rd party code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This is from the Editorskit plugin,*** it is not a part of WordPress. If it's broken you will need to contact their support routes.

*( Based on finding the description text verbatim in a github search, resulting in a file in the preview extension of editorskit )*